# 'To using' from which is 'to' a prep?

Tags: prepositions

> We can cause the lightning to strike where we want it **to** using rockets

From which is 'To' a preposition?
Then why the author used 'To' instead of 'By' or 'With' ?

Or if it's not a preposition. Then what is it?

Answer (score 2):

This **to** is acting as part of the to-infinitive in your sentence.

The meaning of the sentence is:

> We can cause lightning to strike where we want it to **strike**, (by) using rockets.

The second **strike** has been elided but that's what it is saying.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/want
https://www.englishgrammar.org/using-want/

Comment: @Youngho Yes, there should be a comma, as you surmise.